# Prevent non-numeric values while keeping type="Number" in Input element in Firefox

Tags: firefox, sapui5

> EDIT: Thanks to a comment I found out that this problem only occurs in my Firefox (v80.0.1) - let me know if it works in yours, then it can only be a plugin issue, I guess.

The task is simple: Don't allow non-numerical characters to appear in the `Input` element.
[image: restricted character in input]
But because of `type="Number"` it's not working.
I need to keep the `type` property though for mobile devices.

Does anyone have some good solutions for this problem?

Here's the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/eu4d0vr9/

I have tried the `MaskInput` too, but I don't want to set the number to any specific length and also the `description` property does not work anymore then.

P.S.:
I know there are already [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19966417/4120196) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3090810/4120196) here, but they were not asked in the SAPUI5 context and I'd like to know SAPUI5 specific solutions.

Comment: Your example works for me... (only sth. like e+10 is possible)

Comment: So you can't just type in the "a" like me in the screenshot? That's strange...I'm using Firefox, you?

Comment: Chrome Version 85.0...

Comment: Thx for letting me know, it also works in my Chrome - so I guess it's a Firefox-specific problem...

Comment: Unfortunately Firefox hasn't implemented the [specification of the  `<input type="number">`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number):~:text=User%20agents%20must%20not%20allow%20the%20user%20to%20set%20the%20value%20to%20a%20non-empty%20string%20that%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20floating-point%20number.) fully. Also reported as [Bug 1398528](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528).